# How to render the selected dependent/binding options in KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using below code for dependent options

**JS**

```
this.packages = [
    {
        sku: "100",
        name: "Fruits",
        description: "its nice",
        locationOptions: [
            { location: "Orange", price: 20, subOptions: [{ quality: "Average", price: 5 }, { quality: "Imported", price: 4 }] },
            { location: "Apple", price: 30, subOptions: [{ quality: "Good", price: 5 }, { quality: "Imported", price: 5 }] },
            { location: "Banana", price: 5, subOptions: [{ quality: "Normal", price: 6 }, { quality: "Imported", price: 3 }] }
        ]
    }
]
this.selectedPackage = ko.observable();
this.selectedLocation = ko.observable();
this.subOptions = ko.observable('0');
```

I want to display selected values in Html by using

```
<b data-bind="text: name"></b>
<!-- ko with : $parent.selectedLocation -->> <b data-bind="text: location"></b>
<!-- ko with : $parent.subOptions --><b data-bind="text: quality"></b>
<!-- /ko  -->
<!-- /ko  -->
```

Values are are displaying up to second level (**Fruits > Apple**) but third level values (**quality and price**) are not showing, **can any one please tell me where i am doing wrong.**

Comment: your structure like this: your html get `with: packages` outside, so when u call `$parent.selectedLocation` --> same this.selectedLocation in your script; but when you call `$parent.subOptions` inside `ko with : $parent.selectedLocation` so knockout find `subOptions` in `this.selectedLocation` and not found this. u should change `ko with : $parent.subOptions` to `ko with : $root.subOptions `

Comment: Where/how do you update your observables?

Comment: @ Hua  $root.subOptions is showing $root is undefined.

Comment: @ GôTô  i did not get you,sorry i am new to knockout js.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be binding to your object data at the wrong property levels. I've done it to show you below using View Model which you should probably be using and you can now see all levels of data.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-debug.js"></script>
<div>
<!-- ko with : $root.selectedPackage -->
<h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
    <!-- ko with : $root.selectedLocation -->
    <h2 data-bind="text: location"></h2>
    <div data-bind="foreach: subOptions">   
        <h3 data-bind="text: quality"></h3>
        <h3 data-bind="text: price"></h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko  -->
<!-- /ko  -->
</div>

<script>

var ViewModel = function() {
var self = this;
self.packages = [
    {
        sku: "100",
        name: "Fruits",
        description: "its nice",
        locationOptions: [
            { location: "Orange", price: 20, subOptions: [{ quality: "Average", price: 5 }, { quality: "Imported", price: 4 }] },
            { location: "Apple", price: 30, subOptions: [{ quality: "Good", price: 5 }, { quality: "Imported", price: 5 }] },
            { location: "Banana", price: 5, subOptions: [{ quality: "Normal", price: 6 }, { quality: "Imported", price: 3 }] }
        ]
    }
]
self.selectedPackage = ko.observable(self.packages[0]);
self.selectedLocation = ko.observable(self.packages[0].locationOptions[0]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

</script>
```

This gives output like this:

```
#Fruits
##Orange
###Average
###5
###Imported
###4
```

Comment: Thanks, working as expected, but i want to display selected value only, foreach rendering all values.

Comment: Okay, I understand, I've updated the answer and now you should see both a selectedPackage and selectedLocation

Comment: But i have a lot of centralized/dynamic values, i can not go with indexing number.

Comment: you can try someting like `self.selectedPackage(packages.find((f) => f.sku == "100"))` to set the displayed package. I thought you wanted to display the selected package, it is not clear how you want to actually select the package

Comment: Thanks for valuable suggestions +1 , I am trying achieve this in a few more ways.